# Macro for sorting and Sumif

Tags: vba, excel

In a worksheet, I have 5 columns, 1st column contain the file name. I have to split the file name in team,branch,location and week wise in preceding columns. after that have to apply filter and first filter on week from Oldest to newest then on location A to Z. I have 3 weeks data in each report. At the end of the last row, I want to add 3 more row of respective weeks and sum the respective weeks data.i.e eq. for 22-May-17, the next column should add only the data of the row of the same date.

[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj9bh.png)

Comment: (a) Are you using VB.Net or VBA?  Update the tag if it isn't VB.Net.  (b) Post your current code so that we can help you (c) The macros tag says "***DO NOT USE for VBA / MS-Office languages. Use the respective [vba] tags instead.*** A macro is a rule or pattern that specifies how a certain input sequence (often a sequence of characters) should be mapped to an output sequence (also often a sequence of characters) according to a defined procedure." - are you sure that tag is appropriate?

Comment: I am new to stack overflow..it got auto selected. I dont hv the code ready with me to put here...I am trying to get something... kindly help!!

Comment: It's very hard to help you fix your code until we can see your code.  Hopefully someone will notice the edit go through when you **do** have the code with you so that you can paste it in, and be able to help you then.  But from what I have seen, you get more people wanting to help you in the first hour after the question is posted than you do in the rest of its life on the site.